# What does '@' do?... import {ModuleName} from '@ModuleName'

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

#### What does the import '@' mean?

I've seen '@' in a range of modules such as '@react-navigation', '@babel' etc

Does it do anything particular or is it purely aesthetic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that a given package is being released from a given organization. It is an scope to join more packages of that given organization. For example `@ACME/package` means that ACME organization is releasing that package.

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for the answer and the link to additional info.